# Plugin videoPlayer PhoneGap not working

Tags: javascript, android, plugins, cordova, video-player

I'm using cordova 2.9.0 and I installed the videoPlayer plugin:
https://github.com/macdonst/VideoPlayer

I added in config.xml the plugin and in the index.html after declaring cordova.js I included de video.js. Well, when I call the function window.plugins.videoPlayer.play I get the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Error calling method on NPObject.
```

Thanks.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18521807/playing-video-in-phonegap-cordova-app-for-ios-and-android#answer-18582367). See if it helps...