# VideoJS + local videos + phonegap

Tags: cordova, html5-video, video.js

I'm trying to create an application on android/IOS && phonegap. For this application I used the player VideoJS (http://www.videojs.com/).
During my tests inside a browser (desktop or mobile) evrything works fine, I didn't thought that it will be different packaged application (phonegap-build) ... it was :(

I tried to add this plugin https://github.com/amuelli/Html5Video/

I also add this tag inside my config.xml:

```xml
<gap:config-file platform="android" parent="/manifest">
    <application android:hardwareAccelerated="true" />
</gap:config-file>
```

and

```
xmlns:android   = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

My videos are encoded as MP4 and packaged inside the application

Did someone has ever use this player inside phonegap? If yes... how?

Regards,

Comment: Did you see this other post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18521807/playing-video-in-phonegap-cordova-app-for-ios-and-android. Wish I could help, but I don't know phonegap. If you figure it out, I would love to add a guide to using phonegap+video.js to the video.js project.

Comment: Yes, I saw this one, I use the last version of phonegap (3.6.3)