# How to play a YouTube Video in Intel XDK

Tags: android, intel-xdk

I am triying to play a YouTube Video in a HTML5 app from Intel XDK, I insert an iframe normally, but that don't work. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one (as cordova is beneath if all) https://github.com/moust/cordova-plugin-videoplayer

Or this: [Playing video in PhoneGap/Cordova-app for iOs and Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18521807/playing-video-in-phonegap-cordova-app-for-ios-and-android)